# When is it ok to ask a question to which you already have an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have seen a few instances of someone asking a question to which they already have an answer.  I have been told you can answer your own question. So can we develop a flow chart for asking questions to which you already have an answer. When is that OK, helpful or necessary?

Comment: related blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: The key thing for me is that it is not a [stump-the-chumps](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/394/423) question in that you are open to hear perspectives other than what you believe to be the *right* answer. This would mean the question needs to be asked in a way that welcomes other perspectives. So long as that is all good, go for it! I've asked question just to give my own answers several times! If it's something interesting to the community and helpful, by all means do it!

Comment: are you happy with the comments here or do you feel you need a fuller answer(s) Sarah?

Comment: I think the blog.stackoverflow.com/s011/07 link you posted was most helpful.  I did not realize this was actually encouraged!  I have heard many references to "stump the chump" questions.  This still trips me a bit as again it gets into discerning the heart of the OP, can easily be lead to a presumptuous/judgmental/critical approach to especially new contributors.  I think the more one-stop shop, clearly laid out summaries of things like this we have the more chance new members will acclimate.

Comment: @JackDouglas, I've probably asked this before, but I still get a bit lost in here.  Do we have a one stop shop for new members?

Comment: @Sarah the simple tour [is here](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and the more in depth help centre is [here](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help). Both can be accessed from the "help" drop-down in the black bar at the top of the screen and I think new users are prompted to visit both (but there is no harm in reminding them if you think it will help at any time).